# simple doubt when using sax parser (Xerces) in java

Tags: java, sax

I am trying to obtain some data from an xml file using a SAX parser in java- I dont want to do anything for certain elements within the xml (ie ignore them, because I dont require those elements).

Do I just have to ignore those specific elements in "startElement" and "endElement"? Is that the correct way to not do any processing for certain elements?

Comment: If the XML file is not too big, I'd suggest using JDOM, which is far easier to use than SAX (as it lets you navigate the DOM tree, which is most of the time what you want).

Comment: It depends on the application, of course, but SAX is plenty easy to use, and of course doesn't have the "not too big" limitation.

Comment: thank you for your helpful comments...the files that i will read (for which I plan to use SAX) are each 0.6GB to 1Gb... so i guess its all right if i use sax ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, exactly. You're free to process the events you receive in whatever way you'd like, which certainly includes ignoring any uninteresting elements.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to ignore them. Sometimes you're dealing with a system that gives a single set of information, and you are only interested in some. Now, you could always load it in and never use the objects you create, but honestly, just ignoring it seems like the best course of action.